# Node __dirname, process.cwd() are reporting actual directory instead of symlinked one

Tags: javascript, node.js

"Simple" question -- I'm trying to get the path to a directory of a node script, but when I run from a symlinked directory, I keep getting the path to the physical file instead of the path to the symlinked structure.  How do I get the symlinked path?

```bash
/path/to/symlink --> /path/to/real

/path/to/symlink> node echo.js

# echo.js
console.log( __dirname );     // /path/to/real
console.log( process.cwd() ); // /path/to/real
```

[edit] Just for clarification of my own sanity:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
test$ mkdir a
test$ ln -s a b
test$ cd b
b$ node
> process.cwd()
'/test/a'
```

Comment: Isn’t that the _purpose_ of a symlink, that it is largely _transparent_ to the application accessing it (as long as no specific measures are taken to check whether it’s a symlink or not first) …?

Comment: @loganfsmyth -- OSX 10.10, it's _possible_, though I think unlikely, that it's an issue with the Yosemite beta

Comment: You file are soft link, so the output is right.

Comment: @zyklus Ugg, sorry ignore my last comment, I just screwed up my test.

Comment: @BlackMamba -- I'm not questioning the output, I'm asking how to get the linked path

Comment: @zyklus you can create a "hard link", not "soft link".

Comment: @BlackMamba -- You can't hard link directories

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get symlink path through `process.env.PWD` on OSX.

Windows looks as has no this issue.

Comment: The directory in which the file is symlinked, and I want the symlinked directory path, not the original directory path.

Comment: PLEASE take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31436403/177710) on the limits of using `process.env.PWD` - in short, it never changes once a script has started to run.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

execSync('pwd').toString()
```

Running pwd as a child process returns the current directory with symlinks.