# process.env.PWD vs process.cwd()

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, fs

I am using Meteor JS...and within my Meteor app I am using node to query the contents of different directories within the app....

When I use `process.env.PWD` to query the contents of a folder I get a different result from when I use `process.cwd()` to query the results of a folder.

```
var dirServer = process.env.PWD + '/server/';
var dirServerFiles = fs.readdirSync(dirServer);
console.log(dirServerFiles); 
//outputs: [ 'ephe', 'fixstars.cat', 'sepl_30.se1', 'server.js' ]
```

vs

```
var serverFolderFilesDir = process.cwd() +"/app/server";
var serverFolderFiles = fs.readdirSync(serverFolderFilesDir);
console.log(serverFolderFiles); 
//outputs: [ 'server.js' ]
```

using `process.cwd()` only shows `server.js` within the Meteor.

Why is this?
How is `process.cwd()` different from `process.env.PWD`?

Answer (score 57):

They're related but not the same thing.

`process.env.PWD` is the working directory when the *process was started*. This stays the same for the entire process.

`process.cwd()` is the *current* working directory. It reflects changes made via `process.chdir()`.

It's possible to manipulate `PWD` but doing so would be meaningless, that variable isn't used by anything, it's just there for convenience.

For computing paths you probably want to do it this way:

```
var path = require('path');
path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/server')
```

Where `__dirname` reflects the directory the source file this code is defined in resides. It's wrong to expect that `cwd()` will be anywhere near that. If your server process is launched from anywhere but the main source directory all your paths will be incorrect using `cwd()`.

Comment: just to clarify, if we never call `process.chdir()`, it means that `process.cwd()` will be always the same?

Comment: BEWARE that `process.env.PWD` does **not** exist on Windows.