# Is it possible to get the absolute path of a node.js app that was started using a relative path

Tags: node.js, debian, command-line-interface

I have a node.js app located at `/foo/bar/app.js`
If I start it the like this:

```
cd /foo/bar
node app.js
```

lets say it was given PID 555 is it possible to find the absolute path `/foo/bar/app.js` of the app it's running? If I run `ps 555` it will only tell me `app.js` because that's the argument that was passed to node. Is there any way to find out the full path of that node process?

**UPDATE**

I guess I should also point out that I'm not trying to get the path of the current app. It's a separate node app that is trying to find this info. Which may or may not be in the same directory. I'm guessing I'll need to use unix commands through node's Child Process module.

Comment: Consider [`process.env.PWD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414852/process-env-pwd-vs-process-cwd).

Comment: If you don't control that Node program and want to figure out where it is located, consider [`pwdx`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94359/177879).

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin `pwdx` did it! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `pwdx PID` https://linux.die.net/man/1/pwdx

It should give you the working directory of the process.

Comment: Your extra link will show the absolute path of node. I think `app.js` is only the argument passed to node when the command was executed.

Comment: hmm.. gotcha... let me think for a min

Comment: pwdx works perfectly. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.